# React.useRef and using JSX.Element to get object subelements

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-tsx

I have a JSX.Element refinitilized like this that is containg a SVG Element:

```
var fontawesomeIcon = React.useRef<JSX.Element>(    
    <FontAwesomeIcon
        className={classnames({
            'card-content__badge__inner__icon': true,
        })}
        // @ts-ignore
        icon={['fal', iconName]}
    />
);
```

How do I get the path elements that are stored in my ref (in order to change the CSS onto them) ?

Currently I display the icon with this code :

```
{fontawesomeIcon.current}
```